# Why does the following code output System.Int32 instead of System.String?

Tags: c#, type-systems

Why does the following code output `System.Int32` instead of `System.String`?

```
public class A<T>
{
    public class B : A<int>
    {
        public void M() { System.Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)); }
        public class C : B { }
    }
}

public class P
{
    public static void Main() { (new A<string>.B.C()).M(); }
}
```

I got this code form: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1292/eric-lippert-interview

Comment: The short answer is because `B` inherits from `A<int>`.

Comment: Why do you expect it to print _System.String_?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, what is the long answer? Please consider the fact that `(new A<string>.B()).M();` outputs `System.String`, not `System.Int32`.

Comment: @Steve, because as fas as I understand, A<string>.B has T equal to String.

Comment: [Eric Lippert's explanation on his Microsoft blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-one)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Thanks for the link; I have just copied that article to my new blog, at https://ericlippert.com/2007/07/27/an-inheritance-puzzle-part-one/.